# change contents of one script using another in javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

I would like to know if it would be possible to change the contents of this piece of code

```
<a  class="Tips4" href="javascript:void(0)" 
    onclick="javascript:go('http://www.adworkmedia.com/go.php?camp=670&amp;pub=24043&amp;id=2215&amp;sid=&amp;sid2=15545&amp;sid3=gateway&amp;ref=http%3A%2F%2Fcleanfiles.us%2Fgateway2.html', 'trials'); 
    return false;" 
    title="" 
    target="_blank" 
    rel="nofollow" 
    style="color:#379EBC; 
    font-family:Sans-serif, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size:14px;">
 </a>
```

into

```
  <a class="Tips4" 
     href="javascript:void(0)" 
     onclick="javascript:go('http://www.adworkmedia.com/go.php?camp=4556&amp;pub=24043&amp;id=10694&amp;sid=', 'trials'); return false;"      
     title="" 
     target="_blank" 
     rel="nofollow" 
     style="color:#379EBC; 
     font-family:Sans-serif, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px;">
  </a>
```

it is not possible for me to manually change the former because it gets loaded into the webpage by another javascript.

Comment: Does this page load jQuery? If so, or if you can add a script tag to load jQuery, then it ought to be possible.

Comment: @Paul yes it loads jquery.But how change I change the onlick attribute contents. Should I use regex match and then selectively replace contents?

Comment: No, [dont parse html with regex](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).  A [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) can fetch elements to change by identifying the type of element 'a' ,or the class 'Tips4', and other attributes.  jcubic's answer uses that technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a reference to the element you can do this.

```js
var newLink = 'http://www.adworkmedia.com/go.php?camp=4556&pub=24043&id=10694&sid=';
element.onclick = element.onclick.replace(/http:[^']*/, newLink);
```

This will deliberately seek out the link and replace only it, keeping all other javascript the same.
If you want to replace all javascript just overwrite with;

```js
var newJS = "javascript:go('http://www.adworkmedia.com/go.php?camp=4556&pub=24043&id=10694&sid=', 'trials'); return false;";
element.onclick = newJS;
```

---

EDIT

if `element.onclick` doesn't work for you use [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute) and [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getAttribute)

E.g.

```js
element.setAttribute('onclick', element.getAttribute('onclick').replace(/http:[^']*/, newLink));
```

Comment: That should not work. element.onclick is a reference to a function, not some text that you can replace.  elem.onclick = function () { go(<your href>, "trials");}; should be ok though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var code = "javascript:go('http://www.adworkmedia.com/go.php?camp=4556&pub=24043&id=10694&sid=', 'trials'); return false;"

$('.Tips4').attr('onclick', code);
```

Comment: This changes all the elements in class Tips4.  I wonder if `$('a.Tips4')` would be a better selector? If it is selecting too much the OP will need to devise a selector to pin it down.